# Android Switch Compat State Issue

Tags: android, switchcompat

[image: UI Sample]

I want to change the state of child switches from parent switch.

in brief:

case 1: Parent on -> all Child switches on

case 2: Parent off -> all Child switches off

case 3: Child 2 off (Child 1 & 3 ON) -> Parent On

> > Issue
> >     When i on/off all child switches Parent switch should on/off accordingly.

below is my code 
in code case 1,2 & 3 working fine.

switchParent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            if (b) {

                switchChild1.setChecked(true);
                switchChild2.setChecked(true);
                switchChild3.setChecked(true);

            } else {

                switchChild1.setChecked(false);
                switchChild2.setChecked(false);
                switchChild3.setChecked(false);

            }
        }
    }); switchChild1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            setState();
        }
    });

    switchChild2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            setState();
        }
    });


    switchChild3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            setState();
        }
    });
```

> setState()

private void setState() {

```
   if (switchChild1.isChecked() || switchChild2.isChecked() || switchChild3.isChecked()) {

        switchParent.setChecked(true);

    } else {

        switchParent.setChecked(false);

    }

}
```

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Change your setState() method.

```
private void setState() {
if (switchChild1.isChecked() && switchChild2.isChecked() && switchChild3.isChecked()) {
    switchParent.setChecked(true);
} else {
    switchParent.setChecked(false);
}
```

}

Comment: I tried your code but when all switches are ON and i try to OFF any one child switch then all switch state changes to OFF automatically.